# How to align table and plot in rmarkdown html_document

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, kable

How can I align a kable table to be adjacent to a ggplot2 plot in an rmarkdown html_document?

*Foo.Rmd*

````
---
title: "Foo"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

# Table next to plot
```{r echo = FALSE}
kable(head(iris)) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = F)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
```
````

[image]

I tried following the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37115805/2146894) but to no avail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A Kableextra table and a ggplot plot on same row in Rmarkdown (PDF - not Flexdashboard)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858351/a-kableextra-table-and-a-ggplot-plot-on-same-row-in-rmarkdown-pdf-not-flexdas)

Comment: Hmm, that is definitely a similar question but I saw that question as distinctively different since it asks about aligning a table and plot within a *pdf_document*, not an *html_document* as in my case. (Not to mention, the sole answer will not work for my needs since it does not use kable.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A great solution to this issue is provided here by @ErrantBard: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40650190/645206. Please visit and upvote it!
I am copying the solution in my answer to show how it works with your example, and to provide an image of the solution.

To better understand how these `div` tags work, learn more about the bootstrap library. Here is one good link: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/

````
---
title: "Foo"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
```

# Table next to plot
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-md-6">
```{r echo=FALSE}
kable(head(iris)) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = "striped", full_width = FALSE, position="left")
```
</div>

<div class = "col-md-6">
```{r echo=FALSE}
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()
```
</div>
</div>
````

[image]

Comment: This helped so much! Btw, if the table is much longer than the plot, is there a way to  make the table shorter, i.e. crop the table in some way?

Comment: or if that is impossible, align the two plots horizontally?

Comment: Is it possible to make it only in one chunk?. I would like to make many inside a loop but to do that I need it to be in one single chunk I guess.