# side by side display of chart and table in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

Is there a way to display a table and a chart in Rmarkdown? I am trying export the such report to Word and excel not to pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Word is tough. I would recommend pdf or html, but if you have to use word then you can combine the plot and table into a single image using gridExtra

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

data(iris)

myTable = tableGrob(iris[1:10,])
myPlot = ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + geom_point()

grid.arrange(myTable, myPlot, nrow = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks,This approach i tried but facing issues in alignment. I think html can be tried , if you have a better way with html please share.

Comment: I would check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54312894/how-to-align-table-and-plot-in-rmarkdown-html-document)  and follow the links provided.